# XSD - validate that element refers to other elements in XML file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have this simple XML file:

```
<TestBuilder>
    <TestBox testValue="x">test1,test2,test2</TestBox>

    <Test id="test1" />
    <Test2 id="test2" />
    <SomethingElse id="test3" />
</TestBuilder>
```

I would like to write an XSD validation for `TestBox` to validate that all values (splitted by `,`) refer to other element ids in the XML file.

I was able to validate only if the `TestBox` value is not empty, but I have no idea how to split the values by `,` and check the references.

```
<xs:simpleType name="TestBoxType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="TestBoxTagType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="TestBoxType">
            <xs:attribute name="testValue" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Do you know if it is possible? And how to solve with a generic solution?

Comment: I hope that you are given this XML from a '''very''' old system. Otherwise, csv inside an xml is one of the worst cases of anti-pattern out there. If you are creating the system from scratch, do '''not''' include this "technology" in there.

Comment: It comes from very old system and it would be a huge impact on the system to change this XML pattern...  I cannot change it

Comment: Ok. I'm not aware of a way to do that directly, but maybe somebody will propose a solution. If it were me, i would actually do something along the lines of: 1. Read the xml into a String. 2. Find a `TestBox` tag and transform it manually, adding `<item>` in the beginning, `</item>` in the end, and substituting each comma with `</item><item>`. 3. Parse the resulting XML document. Since the transformation happens only in memory, you do not have to change the whole system, but yet you keep yourself sane.

Comment: In my humble, not generally accepted, opinion, using XSD to enforce business rules that are above "structural requirements" is a bad choice of technology. Business rules have a way/habit of evolving with "except if", "only when", "not after" exceptions that fastly grow out of what XSD and regexps will buy you. You may end up with some requirements being met by XSD just fine, some you'll shoehorn with questionnable workarounds, and a few others that just won't work. I'd implement business controls my own way from the get go.

Comment: Can you use Schematron, or any general-purpose programming language to enforce those rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML Schema does support lists, but only space separated, not comma separated (also, note that the document was not well-formed because of a missing `/` in the end tag for TestBox). That is, what you are asking for should be possible if you can pre-process the document to use spaces instead of commas:

```
<TestBuilder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <TestBox testValue="x">test1 test2 test2</TestBox>

    <Test id="test1" />
    <Test2 id="test2" />
    <SomethingElse id="test3" />
</TestBuilder>
```

The above document is valid against the following schema, in which you can see that the type TestBoxTagType extends `xs:IDREFS`, which is a list of `IDREF`s. Similarly, all `id` attributes are defined as having the type `xs:ID` for the ID mechanism to work.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="TestBuilder">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TestBox" type="TestBoxTagType"/>
                <xs:element name="Test" type="withIDType"/>
                <xs:element name="Test2" type="withIDType"/>
                <xs:element name="SomethingElse" type="withIDType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="TestBoxTagType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:IDREFS">
                <xs:attribute name="testValue" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="withIDType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```